# Best way to do something after parsing command line arguments

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, command-line-tool

I want to know some good approaches in executing code blocks based on the command line options passed to the program. The program should scale with number of arguments. For eg:

```
if (option1 and option2)
    do something;
if(option1 or option2)
    do something;
if (option3 and option4)
    do something;
```

So, I want my program to be robust and handle all the cases for the options provided. I know I can use if-else or switch statement and achieve this, but this requires a lot of processing. Are these the only way? Is there a better way to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: How best to approach command-line argument processing depends heavily on what kind of processing you want to perform.  You have all the tools available that you ever do.  You might consider looking to functions or libraries oriented toward command-line processing, such as GNU getarg, but ultimately these just help you determine what the arguments *are*.  You still have to write roughly the same code for choosing what to do with them.

Comment: I am looking to perform basic processing, where I want to find the best way to branch of and do something. I was wondering if I can avoid the if-else logic for all the options.

Answer (score 1):

At the end, you need to do the decision-making yourself based on the input provided.

However, if you want to make this clean, you can try something like this:

=>> In first step, you can get the state. This will help in collating all the conditional-branches at one places

```
if (option1 and option2)
    set STATE1;
if(option1 or option2)
    set STATE2;
if (option3 and option4)
    set STATE3;
```

=>> Now, once the states are set clearly, you can try doing:

```
case STATE1:
    do something;
case STATE2:
    do something;
case STATE3:
    do something;
```

May be it is not the answer you are looking for. But this will surely help you in structuring your program in better way.

Comment: I actually made use of 2D arrays and switch cases and built a good decision making algorithm that decides what to do with the command line options. Thanks!

Comment: @shank22 great to hear that you were able to proceed.